# Ring of quotients (fractions) and central localization

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, localization

I am studying ring of quotients and ore localization.Itry to find ring of quotients any given ring $R$.But, My attempt is futile.

$\textbf{Definition:}$ A ring $R'$ denoted by $RS^{-1}$ is said to be a right ring of fractions (or quotients) with respect to $S\subseteq R$ if there is a given ring homomorphism $\phi:R\rightarrow R'$ such that :

$\textbf{(a)}$ $\phi$ is $S$-inverting.(It means that every element of $S$ invertible under $\phi$)

$\textbf{(a)}$ Every element of $R'$ has the form $\phi(a)\phi(s)^{-1}$ for some $a\in R$ and $s\in S$

$\textbf{(c)}$ ker$\phi=\{r\in R: rs=0 \ \  \textit{for some} \ \ s\in S\}$

$\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $R$ be a domain and $S=R-\{0\}$. The condition $$aR\cap bR\neq (0) \ \textit{for} \ S=R-\{0\}$$ is called $\textbf{(right) Ore condition}$ on $R$.

> - Thus, the domain $R$ is right (resp,left) Ore iff $R$ satisfies the right (resp. left) Ore condition.

$\textbf{Definiton:}$ Let $R\subseteq Q$ be rings. We say that $R$ is a $\textbf{right order}$ in $Q$ if

$\textbf{1}$ Every regular element(neither a left $0$-divisor and nor a right $0$-divisor) is a unit(invertible) in $Q$.

$\textbf{2}$ Every element of $Q$ has the form $as^{-1}$, where $a\in R$ and $s$ is a regular element of $R$. ( Left orders are defined similarly.)

$\textbf{Proposition:}$ The ring $R$ is right Ore iff it is a right order in some ring $Q$. In this case $Q\cong Q^r_{cl}(R)$ over $R$.

$\textbf{Example:}$ Let.
$R=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z}\\
 0& \mathbb{Z} \\
\end{bmatrix} $. Let us consider the multiplicative set  $$S=\bigg\{\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & c \end{bmatrix}:a,b,c\in \Bbb Z, a\neq0 \bigg\}$$

whose element are not necessarily regular. Using the homomorphism $\phi:R\rightarrow \Bbb Q$ defined by $\phi\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & c \end{bmatrix} =a$, it is easy to check that $\Bbb Q$ is a right ring of fractions of $R$ with respect to $S$. Therefore $RS^{-1}$ exists and isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.

> - Also, we can find central localization with respect to $T=\{I.n:0\neq 0\in \Bbb Z\}$.

Then, we see easily that the central localization $RT^{-1}$ gives the ring $Q=\begin{bmatrix}
\Bbb Q & \Bbb Q\\
0 & \Bbb Q \end{bmatrix}$ via the map $\phi:R\rightarrow Q$, $\phi(r)=r/1$. It is easy to see that any regular element of $R$ is a unit in $Q$. Therefore, $R$ is an order in $Q$ and $Q=Q^r_{cl}(R)=Q^{l}_{cl}(R)$.

> - I need central localization and right ring of fractions following ring.

$\textbf{Example:}$ 
Let
$R=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{Z} & 2\mathbb{Z}\\
\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z} \\
\end{bmatrix} $.

Help please.

Comment: Undeleting this largely to give the OP a chance to improve it, as they are sincerely trying to climb out of a question ban and have contributed useful answers. I think there is an interesting question in here.

Comment: Ok. I will try.

Comment: 1. In the first definition, you called a ring a *right ring of fractions of $R$ with respect to $S$* if [...]. At the end, you ask for "the" right ring of fractions. Which $S$ is meant? 2. What do you mean by "central localization"? The only place where you used it you defined a set which is not so clear... I read: I dot n such that 0 \neq 0 \in Z

Comment: @ frame95 : $(1)$.I gave you an example of how  to choice of $S$ would be. The main question is how to make  choice of $S$.. $S$ any multiplicative subset of ring. $2.$ the (right) ring of fractions of  you get with respect to center($=S$)  is called central localization.